# Which HTML5 tags can I use without worrying about browser compatibility?

Tags: html, browser, cross-browser, compatibility

I am building a web app for use on PCs. What are the HTML5 tags to stay away from to prevent compatibility issues with Browsers like IE8 and above?

Note: Most questions are 1-3 years old on this subject.

Comment: Check http://caniuse.com and http://html5please.com for up-to-date browser compatibility information.

Comment: @deceze any links to know more about shims?

Comment: [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com) is a good resource

Comment: IMHO you can't use anything in web development without worrying about browser compatibility...

Comment: See [___The three levels of HTML5 usage___](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-levels). Level 1 stuff can be used without a problem. Level 2 features degrade gracefully. Level 3 features require a polyfill if support for older browsers is a concern.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You asked what HTML5 tags to stay away from.

Well Some of the tags from HTML5 from my knowledge were made for semantic reasons. like the following for example.

```
<article> <section> <aside> <nav> <header> <footer> ..ect
```

These are almost fine to work with, and just require a bit of CSS eg. `display: block;` to work normally in most browsers, though in older browsers ie. Internet Explorer you are required to create a element in Javascript in order for it to be compatible.

**Here is an example.**

```
document.createElement('article');
```

Would set the `<article>` element up for use in older Internet Explorer.

For more advanced HTML5 tags that require Javascript functionality to work are some like the following.

```
<audio> <video> <source> <track> <embed> And most importantly <canvas>
```

These elements are harder to support/shiv in older browsers. Although I have included a link to cross browser polyfills at the bottom, although I haven't personally investigated them.

So I would say that any element that doesn't require Javascript functionality are perfectly fine to use with a tiny bit of cross browser support code.

If your targeting **>IE8** then you should be fine if you use a shiv.

What do I call older browsers? **< IE9**

Browser support for HTML5 tags today is.

```
<section>, <article>, <aside>, <header>, <footer>, 
<nav>, <figure>, <figcaption>, <time>, <mark>
```

Are not supported by Internet Explorer less than **8** but can be fixed like this.

**CSS:**

```
section, article, aside, header, footer, nav, figure, figcaption{
   display: block;
}
time, mark { 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```js
var elements = ['section', 'article', 'aside', 'header', 'footer', 'nav', 'figure', 'figcaption', 'time', 'mark'];
for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ) {
    document.createElement(elements[i]);
}
```

And `<audio> <video> <canvas>` are not supported in **< IE 9**

The `<embed>` element has partial support in **> IE8**

---

**You should also look into this tag.**

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

This `meta` tag tells Internet Explorer to display the page in highest IE mode available, instead of going into compatibility mode and rendering the page as IE7 or 8 would do. More info on that [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge).

---

## HTML5 Helper Links

---

> For a Kick Start you can check out **[HTML5 BoilerPlate](http://html5boilerplate.com)**
>
> For browser compatibility support tables you can check out - **http://caniuse.com/**
>
> HTML5 Shiv - **https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv**
>
> List of HTML5 Polyfills - **[https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/...](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills)**

**Update**

As mentioned in a comment

> Be careful with the meta tag X-UA-Compatible. If you use something like html5 boilerplate that has conditional comments surrounding the  element (this also happens with the html5 doctype IIRC), you may run into problems with IE9 forcing itself into IE7 standards mode even with the tag. IE strikes again

You may want to look into this, I have nothing to back this up at the moment.

Comment: Also, if you can specify, what is older IE? 6,7,8?

Comment: Generally Older IE is < IE9

Comment: Be careful with the meta tag X-UA-Compatible. If you use something like html5 boilerplate that has conditional comments surrounding the `<html>` element (this also happens with the html5 doctype IIRC), you may run into [problems](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/378) with IE9 forcing itself into IE7 standards mode even with the tag. IE strikes again.

Comment: Thanks for the info, any blog posts or some info that I can add into the answer regarding that issue would be good **:)**

Answer (score 12):

Generally, there are issues.

I've been told that your question is worded to ask about HTML 5 *tags* but it is also useful
to look at the new features in light of any Javascript you might find or write.

In practice, the recommended method is to test for the existence of the feature
rather than a specific browser.  The [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) script may be helpful in this regard, but there are also reports of [undetectable features in HTML5](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/Undetectables).

Some features like `local storage` go back to IE8.

Others, like `FileReader`, require IE10/Firefox21/Chrome27

For current information, try http://caniuse.com

Comment: I must note that localStorage & fileReader are not HTML Tags, The OP asked what HTML5 tags have compatibility issues.

Comment: Oh, yeah.  There is this big list of semantic tags that is getting pushed in HTML5 as a way to make your page more machine readable and perhaps more SEO friendly [or perhaps not]. There are a few new input elements.  I suppose some of these might have issues in one or more browsers.  I would think caniuse might have that information...

Answer (score 8):

Write HTML 5 like you normally would and use [Shims](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) to ensure compatibility with older browsers. You only need to be careful with Javascript APIs really, because those are hardly shim-able. If you're trying to stick to baseline HTML 4 for compatibility, there's no point in using HTML 5.

Comment: I'd gladly use `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the top line instead of those cursed long ugly things foisted on us in the before-times.

Comment: If that's the only thing that changes between your HTML 4 and "HTML 5" documents... what's the point? :)

Answer (score 4):

For a quick comparison of what tags are available in what browsers, and what level of support for each tag, [html5test.com](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome28/ff24/ie10.html) is a great resource.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an HTML5 compatability matrix

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5)

Comment: Do note: "This article's factual accuracy may be compromised due to out-of-date information. Please update this article to reflect recent events or newly available information. (March 2013)"

Comment: Yeah that is possibly true but in general google ``html5 compatability`` I'm sure there are many resources.

Answer (score 2):

Also, for the best cross browser compatibility, i suggest you use this reset.css created by Eric Meyer.
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
This makes the elements that differ from a browser to another, to behave the same in all browsers.