# HTML5 Tags and compatibility

Tags: html, compatibility

I decided to build my latest website using HTML5 tags like `<main>, <aside>, <header>, <nav>` and more. I built the layout using HTML5 tags and the cross-browser compatibility is horrible. Why should i use these tags when i could just use divs? is there a plugin like Shim that fixes these issues on all browsers?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide us some code so that we can help you.

Comment: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Awesome. Normalize so far has fixed almost every layout issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which HTML5 tags can I use without worrying about browser compatibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223540/which-html5-tags-can-i-use-without-worrying-about-browser-compatibility)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if it isn't supported across browsers, then you should use divs.
The new HTML5 tags add semantic search capability to your HTML documents.

You can use caniuse.com to find out what's supported where.