# How can I center a div inside another div?

Tags: html, css

How can I center one div inside another div?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried removing the width/height from the image tag? `<img src="https://image.ibb.co/bE3eVF/my_Picture.jpg">`

Answer (score 1):

You have some fundamenatal syntactic issues to face here:

- You should stop using `div` to encase image tags and instead use the `figure` tag in HTML5.
- You should (as commented by **Hevlastka**) remove the size defined in the `<img>` tag and have the sizing *only*  defined in CSS.
- You have set a `max-width` without setting a `width` which can [cause issues](http://caniuse.com/#search=max-width) on IE based browsers.

  - IE10 and IE11 do not appear to support overriding min-width or max-width values using the initial value.
  - IE7 doesn't support min-width on input button/submit button/reset button.
  - max-width doesn't work with images in table cells in IE.

---

- Using [Normalize CSS](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) is **highly recommended** (*esp. if you don't want to use javascript*).
- You should try and get out of the habit of using `<style>` as soon as possible and instead put your CSS in its own specific file to be called by the HTML file.

---

Edits to your code that I've used to make it work for me on IE 11 and Edge:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title is REQUIRED in HTML head area</title>
    <style>

        div {
            text-align:center;
        }
        /* 
           The picture and the div must be Centered 
           inside their container! 
        */
        figure {
            border: 1px solid red;
            padding:20px;
            text-align:center;
            display:inline-block;
            margin:auto;
        }

        img {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 100%;
            max-width:640px;
            height: auto;
            margin:auto;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <figure>
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/bE3eVF/my_Picture.jpg">
    </figure>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RobertSmith [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223540/which-html5-tags-can-i-use-without-worrying-about-browser-compatibility). In general I would say stop caring about old browsers, while they are still cared for, they will not ever be updated to newer browsers. As a very basic solution you can simply revert `figure` to `div` and mark it with an appropriate class accordingly.

Comment: @RobertSmith add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your outer div and that will work correctly. It's because w3Fools isn't very good

Comment: @RobertSmith you seem to also have a fundamental misunderstanding on the cascading effect of ***Cascading* Style Sheets**, the rules you give to the outer div are also applied to the inner div. This is really inefficient and really tedious to work out what's going on. Set each div to have it's own calss and set these classes so each div has a clear set of rules *just for that div*.

Comment: @RobertSmith with respect, you need to stop whining and instead take the comments I've made above and use them to expand your own knowledge. Use a google search of "why should I use figure tag in HTML5", or similar. I am not going to give you all the answers you want, just like that, it's worthless to me an it's worthless to you. research and **learn** stuff yourself using your own volition. Same with Stack Overflow syntax (`@`) it's all in the help section, if you bother to read it. I've given you enough pointers you should be able to solve your own questions from here on in. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Modernnizr.js` is solving the problem.

Add this between your `<head>` tags.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js"></script>
```

and remove `display: table;` from your CSS.

[image]

Comment: @RobertSmith don't you think this is a criteria you should state in your question? Murat Seker is not a mind reader.

Comment: anyway I hope your problem has been solved. enjoy stackoverflow ;)